# Changing the elements of an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have the following script:

PHP:

```
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++){
    echo '<li id="p'.$i.'" style="display: none;" onclick="click('.$i.')">'.$i.'</li>';
}
```

Javascript:

```
var arr_p=[];

function click(x){
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
        a = document.getElementById('p'+i);
        if(a.style.display=='inline'){
            arr_p.push(i);
        }
    }   

    if(x==arr_p.length){
        document.getElementById('p'+1).style.display='none';
    }   
}
```

As you can see,i declared an array outside of the function so i can change the elements inside(atleast for variable string works).Then i catch each html element that have display inline from 1 to 10 and insert them into arr_p.

When a user click on the last element(which is 10),if it's equal with the array length(which is 10),the first html element will get the display none,so when the function goes  again,it should check for the first 10 values with display inline,and insert them in arr_p.

I checked the array length with console.log , and each time the function do his job,the new array elements are added instead of replacing the old ones.I need the new elements that are pushed into the array,to replace the old ones.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could just empty the array (arr_p=[]) each time the for loop starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to clear the array before the loop.You can use:

```
arr_p.length=0;
```

or

```
arr_p=[];
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to clear the array every time you click. re-initailize the array so it might works fine